# 403 Invalid scope claims/roles

Tags: api, token, microsoft-graph-api

I've seen this question asked before, but I'm reproducing all the steps and at loss of where the issue is.

- I have an app in Graph with requested app permission Reports.Read.All
  (Admin). No other permissions requested.
- The admin has authorised this app (client credentials flow)
- I'm getting a token via client credentials flow
- However, any API call
  to the Reports results in 403 Invalid scope claims/roles (e.g.
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserCounts(period='D7') with Authorization: Bearer *token*)
- When I'm decoding the token, it has no reference to the scope whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Resolved: I needed to register the app with Azure AD and not Graph. Will test more tomorrow.

Comment: You can put this as the answer, not a comment so that it can be removed from the unanswered queue

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: I needed to register the app with Azure AD and not Graph.

Comment: What do you mean by register the app? When you create an app/service principle it is in AD?